# Web log file analysis software to measure search crawlers

Tags: log-files, analytics, search-engine, web-crawler

I need to analyze the search engine crawling going on in my site.  Is there a good tool for this?  I've tried AWStats and Sawmill.  But both of those give me very limited insight into the crawling.  I need to know information like how many unique/distinct webpages in a section of my site was crawled by a specific crawler within a time period.

Google analytics doesn't track crawling at all due to its javascript tracking mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Clarity](https://github.com/tobi/clarity) is a front end interface similar to Splunk.

[Logstash](https://code.google.com/p/logstash/) should be able to help you with what you need.